# Is IMAPStore and IMAPFolder in JavaMail Thread Safety?

Tags: java, multithreading, jakarta-mail, exchange-server

## Background

I am going to implement a program to fetch mails from MS Exchange 2007 server.
Due to the architecture design, I have to run multiple threads(NOT Fixed quantity) to connect to the same mailbox & same folder to fetch mails.

JavaMail: 1.5.6
Exchange: 2007

## Issue

Each thread will get a email-id and connect by using `IMAPStore`, then open an `IMAPFolder`, finally fetch email by searching email-id. Finally close the `IMAPFolder` & `IMAPStore`.

When the program runs for a while, the threads increase, I will get below exception:

```
javax.mail.StoreClosedException: failed to create new store connection
at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPFolder.throwClosedException(IMAPFolder.java:3368)
at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPFolder.doCommand(IMAPFolder.java:3497)
at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPFolder.exists(IMAPFolder.java:560)
at com.myco.myapp.MessageHandler.getFolder(MessageHandler.java:68)
```

I guess maybe there is an connection limitation on Exchange server, so I ask the Exchange admin and he said the connection limitation(to each mailbox) is set to 16.

Then I did a test:

1. Connect by `IMAPStore`
2. In a loop, keep open `IMAPFolder`(with the same folder name) but NOT close them

then I got the same exception after opened the 15th `IMAPFolder` and try to open the 16th one.

## My Question

I have read the source code of IMAPFolder and found most of its functions are `synchronized`. Is it safe to use only one global `IMAPStore` & `IMAPFolder` object shared by multiple threads?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's safe to use an IMAPStore or IMAPFolder from multiple threads, but each open IMAFolder gets a single connection to the server so your concurrency will be limited by that single connection.  Depending on your what processing you're doing for each message, it might be better to have a single thread open the folder and fetch all the information it needs for each message and pass that information to a thread pool to process in parallel.

Comment: Tks Bill, on the Exchange server level, does it means every time I call IMAPStore.getFolder(folderName), a new connection to server will be established?

Comment: No, Folder.open.